# soap-response: is Content-Length required in http-header?

Tags: php, soap, lighttpd

I didn't found a answer to this in w3.org.

Almost all examples include the content length in the soap-response http-header.

first Q:
But is it technically necessary?

i am struggling with an soap-service where the php-soap-library (PEAR SOAP_Server) is setting the right content length of the response xml, but lighttpd afterwards is compressing the content, and so i am getting a smaller response than the content length.

And some applications like soapUI is waiting for alle the content (set by the http-header) to arrive.

second Q:

- Who is behaving/configured wrong in this chain? php -> lighttpd -> soapUI
- is it the php-code which sets the unzipped content-length?
- is it lighttpd which compresses the response, but doesn't override or delete the
  content-length header?
- Or is it soapUI, which shouldn't wait 15sec for further content?

**EDIT:**
Further investigation revealed, that the php-script is compressing the content itself and is setting always the umcompressed Content-length, not lighttpd.

Nevertheless [Tom van der Woerdts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377037/tom-van-der-woerdt)  answer is very helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First question**
No, as the [HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) doesn't require the `Content-Length` header and SOAP is built on top of HTTP. It's possible that your SOAP client requires it, but SOAP itself doesn't. (The [SOAP spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3288.txt) doesn't even contain the word "length")

**Second question**
PHP is probably wrong there. It shouldn't be setting a `Content-Length` header. lighttpd is probably also a bit wrong, as it should really override the `Content-Length` header if it changes the content. And soapUI could correct for the issue, as SOAP is based on XML which has a very clear EOF (the closing tag).

I recommend not letting PHP set a `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Do you remember which part of the RFC says that the Content-Length header isn't required?  I've been looking for it.

Comment: Section 4.4 (Message length), the part about compatibility with HTTP/1.0